# range bar on click listener dosen't work

Tags: android, seekbar

Im using this library for range bar:

https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar

the `OnClickListener()` does not work. This is my xml:

```
<com.appyvet.rangebar.RangeBar
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rangebar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:onClick="Click"
    />
```

with `android:onClick="Click"` and with this function:

```
public void Click(View v) {
    Log.e(TAG,"come");
    userScroll=false;
}
```

it doesn't come inside function even with this function:

```
rangeBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
```

I want to use this function and not a `setOnRangeBarChangeListener()`.

Comment: there is contradiction...you are using two clicklisteners

Comment: @BajiraoShinde neither setOnClickListener nor Click individually does not work I tried.

Comment: @joefayyaz did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using one either use Click or setOnClickListener.
Dont use Both as they contradict.
Hope it helps.

Comment: @joefayyaz one thing i noticed is provide some height to rangebar as the code you posted height attribute is missing